# Gradle build failed for empty project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I just created a project in spring boot, the project is clean (zero changes) just created and at first I wanted to build it with the command: `./gradlew clean build` , but the build does not go through I get: `BUILD FAILED` (**Task :test FAILED**)  `What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':test'. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` I have no idea why I'm getting an error in an application where I haven't modified anything yet. What could be the cause of this? How can I build this application?

```
SpringbootServerApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException at DataSourceProperties.java:182
```

**gradle.build**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
```

Comment: Could you show us what is at DataSourceProperties.java:182?

Comment: assuming you used https://start.spring.io, what version of spring-boot was chosen ? share your build.gradle

Comment: @ShaharTI I have attached the build.gradle file in the post

Comment: Seems like DB is not configured on your TEST-profile or tests.
Make sure you're using a real one (real/testcontainer/inmemopry) and correct properties.

Comment: @LenglBoy If I run with the -x test parameter, the build goes through, just wondering why I can't run the project I just created, the test class is empty

Comment: @VichynewSTB the gradle param `-x test` is excluding the test. So since you have configured a datasource your app will need a DB. Maybe your Test-Scope does not contain a DB connection to the DB can not be found which is required.
Add a application.properties file to test/resources and configure a DB or make spring skip the DB connection to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I think you have default test and you dont have  main method that starts application. Maybe you can write some code to provide spring application to boot. Main method is enough for you. contextLoads() method test the application context be up or not. You need configure datasource as well. In your stacktrace I can see that driver is missing.